# How to read contents of datasets of a h5py file into a numpy array given a list of keys?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

Inputs to my function are a h5py file and a text file. Text file has two columns. First column has some utterance information and second column has the speaker information (for that utterance). The keys of h5py file (created using create_datasets) are the utterances (first column of the file). Each of this datasets will have a numpy array (only one) of fixed dimension (600, ). The h5py file has more utterances than the utterances in the text file. Some of the utterances in the text file may not be present in h5py file.

Expected outputs of my function: two numpy arrays

1st array (let us call it X) should be of shape ((nutts, 600),  dtype='float')

2nd array (let us call it y) should be of shape ((nutts,), dtype='int' )

where nutts are the number of utterances of the text file that are (actually) present in the h5file (nutts <= total_lines_in_text_file)

NOTE: I don't know the nutts in advance. I have to create X and y dynamically.

Method for creating X should be clear from the above description:

For the first utterance in text file, I check if that utterance exists as a key in h5file. If it exists, I take the numpy array (600 dimensional) and put in first row of X and then iterate (Reminder I don't know 'nutts' in advance so I cannot pre initialize X with zeros. So I saved them as a dict and tried to convert dict to a numpy array once I have them all in place

More about y:
All the nutts may correspond to nspkrs (nspkrs <= nutts). Multiple utterances can get mapped to same speaker. I want to encode the speaker information of each utterance in a numpy array format. For spkr1 I give a label of 0, for spkr n I give a label of n-1.

Here is what I did:

```html
h5f = h5py.File('some.h5', 'r')

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


def load_data(h5f, src_u2s_list):

    with open(src_u2s_list) as f:

        content = f.read().splitlines()

    utt2ivec = {}
    utt2lbl = {}
    spk2spk_class = {}
    spk_id = -1
    for u2s in content:
        utt, spk = u2s.split()
        if spk not in spk2spk_class.keys():
            spk_id += 1
            spk2spk_class[spk] = spk_id

        if utt in h5f.keys():
            utt2ivec[utt] = h5f[utt][:]
            utt2lbl[utt] = spk2spk_class[spk]
        else:
            print("Utterance {0} does not exist in h5file".format(utt))

    data_X = pd.Series(utt2ivec)
    data_y = pd.Series(utt2lbl)

    return data_X.values, data_y.values
```

Main considerations:

1. the h5file has around 100,000 utterances and text file has around 70000 utterances. So this code runs **very slow**
2. I am new to using h5py files. Suggestions or entire restructuring of the code is welcome.
3. I want to avoid using pandas.
4. **Very Important**: The order of the utterances in X and y should be the same. That means the rows of X and y should correspond to same utterance.

Sorry for a long description. I want to make things clear to avoid confusion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Other than speed, are you happy with the creation of `utt2ivec adn` and `utt2lbl`?  Looks like those are dictionaries with array values.   Your description may be clear to you, but to the casual viewer it looks complicated.  We could use some concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we want to collect a bunch of arrays (of equal size) into 2d array, we first append them to a list, and then create the array from that at the end:

```
utt2ilist = []
...
    if utt in h5f.keys():
        utt2ilist.append(h5f[utt][:])
    ...
utt2iarr = np.array(utt2ilist)
```

I don't know of any way of loading multiple datasets at once, at least not with `h5py`.  You just have to find the relevant `key` and load it as you do.   If you have a large number of datasets, each relatively small (600 elements) this could take time.  Watch out if the the datasets differ in size - then the result will be an object dtype array, not a 2d one.

I assume the `spk2spk_class[spk]` can be collected in a similar list.

Using lists like this will order them in the order that they are read.  Using the dictionaries and pandas will index them by `utt`.  With a dictionary intermediary you may loose information about the read order.

I was going to suggest `defaultdict` for the `spk2spk_class`, but you aren't counting the objects, but rather just giving them unique ids.

My guess is that the slowness comes from just reading a large number of uterances, not from the collection mechanism itself.  But I don't have your data to test.