# How to create an 3d numpy array with unknown shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am reading H5PY file. It has 10K datasets in it. Each of datasets has the following shape : [5, unknown (depends on each dataset), 2048]

In order to utilize the vectorized numpy or tf performance, what would be your recommendation to read data in an efficient way?

Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of operations you want to do on the data. Please update your question with that crucial information.

Comment: There's only one way to read `h5py` datasets, which is well explained in its docs.  A dataset might have been created `resizable` in one dimension, but actual shape is easily found.  There's no 'bulk' read. [How to read contents of datasets of a h5py file into a numpy array given a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641137)

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful link. By the way, I just wanted to ask: Is there a way to get the whole content of the H5PY file as numpy type ?